# Manga where a glitch forces a guy to fight the intro boss for a thousand years

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I can't remember much but what I do remember is that the main character gets pulled away from his world and is forced to fight this trial boss, then he was supposed to end up going back to his world, but it glitched and he ended up fighting it for like a 1000 years until he killed it, which then sent him back to his world. His hair color switches to white when he powers up.

Comment: What color is his hair before he powers up?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots It depends. How long did he yell for it to change color?

Answer (score 1):

It might be *Limit Breaker*, it’s a South Korean manhwa that has around ten chapters.

In it the main character gets summoned in a tutorial room where he's forced to fight a monster but it ends up glitching and he's stuck there for 1000 years until he breaks out.

Comment: If so, it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/247544/manhwa-about-a-person-getting-stuck-in-the-tutorial/247547#247547

Comment: Can you explain why it matches so that there's more than just a name? Feel free to crib anything you want out of my answer in the link above.

Comment: In the future when you want to add information please [edit] your answer to do so rather than adding a new answer. For now I’ve deleted your other answer here and added the information it added to this answer.