# Manhwa about a person getting stuck in the "tutorial"

Tags: story-identification, comics, manga

I read the first chapter and then forgot about it but the main things I can remember are that there was a blue or black box training room with a giant monster in it and the MC got stuck in there for a long time. The MC got really OP and whenever he got serious his hair turned white. His mom was also stuck in the hospital

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you add when and where you read this?  And maybe anything else you might recall about how the characters dressed, what the monster looked like, etc.  Every extra detail can help.

Comment: *The Tutorial Tower of the Advanced Player*? No white hair, though.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the  voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

[This fellow](https://www.reddit.com/r/Isekai/comments/mtmh03/help_me_remember_this_manhwa/) identified it as *[Limit Breaker](https://myanimelist.net/manga/135021/Limit_Breaker)*:

[image: Image of Kim with white hair]

> Due to an unknown error, Kin Kinong has been stuck in the awakening test for 3000 years. In the real world, 10 years have passed, and it is infested with monsters and dungeons. The battle now begins for Kim Kibong, who has returned to the highest level, to restore the world as it was before.

Found with a search for `manhwa stuck in tutorial "white hair"`